# Imagenes no ocupan el 100% del contenedor div para slider

Tags: html, css3, div, slider, width

Estoy intentando realizar un slider con html y css, pero tengo el problema de que las
imágenes no ocupan el 100% del contenedor. Necesito realizar esto únicamente utilizando html y css de momento. Espero puedan ayudarme a comprender porqué está pasando esto, muchas gracias!

[image: No termina de ocupar el ancho para el slider]

//Html

```
    <div class="slider">
      <div class="images">
        <input type="radio" name="slide" id="img1" checked>
        <input type="radio" name="slide" id="img2">
        <input type="radio" name="slide" id="img3">
        <input type="radio" name="slide" id="img4">

        <img src="/assets/carousel-images/ice-cream-1.jpg" class="ice1" alt="">
        <img src="/assets/carousel-images/ice-cream-2.jpg" class="ice2" alt="">
        <img src="/assets/carousel-images/ice-cream-3.jpg" class="ice3" alt="">
        <img src="/assets/carousel-images/ice-cream-4.jpg" class="ice4" alt="">
      </div>

      <div class="dots">
        <label for="img1"></label>
        <label for="img2"></label>
        <label for="img3"></label>
        <label for="img4"></label>
      </div>
    </div>
```

//Css

```
.slider{
    position: relative;
    width: 80%;
    overflow:hidden;
    margin-left: 10%;
    background-color: red;
    /* border: 1px solid black; */
    border-radius: 10px;
}

.images{
    display:flex;
    width: 100%;
    height: 700px;
}

.images img{
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    transition: all 1s ease;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
}

.images input{
    display: none;
}

.dots{
    display:flex;
    justify-content: center;
    margin: 5px;
}

.dots label{
    height: 20px;
    width: 20px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    border: 3px solid black ;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition:  all 0.5s ease;
    margin: 5px;
}

.dots label:hover{
    background: black;
}

#img1:checked ~ .ice1{
    margin-left: 0;
}

#img2:checked ~ .ice2{
    margin-left: -100%;
}
#img3:checked ~ .ice3{
    margin-left: -200%;
}
#img4:checked ~ .ice4{
    margin-left: -300%;
}
```

Este es el código, estoy intentando de varias maneras pero no lo consigo, al parece cuando le saco el height a .images que es el contenedor, este tomar todo el ancho, pero cuando quiero darle el height que yo quiero, la imagen se deforma.

Comment: Te falta agregar a la regla `.images img` la propiedad `flex-shrink: 0;`. No lo pongo como respuesta, porque las imágenes no se van a escalar correctamente y se va a ver feo. Imagino que tambien te gustaria que se van bien, no?

Comment: Muchas gracias!! Funcionó perfectamente y las imágenes se ven bien jaja si quieres ponlo como respuesta y te pongo como solución!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Te falta agregar a la regla `.images img` la propiedad `flex-shrink: 0;`

#### Ejemplo:

```css
.slider {
  position: relative;
  width: 80%;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin-left: 10%;
  background-color: red;
  /* border: 1px solid black; */
  border-radius: 10px;
}

.images {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  height: 700px;
}

.images img {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  transition: all 1s ease;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
  flex-shrink: 0;
}

.images input {
  display: none;
}

.dots {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  margin: 5px;
}

.dots label {
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 3px solid black;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
  margin: 5px;
}

.dots label:hover {
  background: black;
}

#img1:checked~.ice1 {
  margin-left: 0;
}

#img2:checked~.ice2 {
  margin-left: -100%;
}

#img3:checked~.ice3 {
  margin-left: -200%;
}

#img4:checked~.ice4 {
  margin-left: -300%;
}
```

```html
<div class="slider">
  <div class="images">
    <input type="radio" name="slide" id="img1" checked>
    <input type="radio" name="slide" id="img2">
    <input type="radio" name="slide" id="img3">
    <input type="radio" name="slide" id="img4">

    <img src="https://media.istockphoto.com/photos/ice-cream-sundae-waffle-cone-with-chocolate-pieces-and-walnut-picture-id517803602" class="ice1" alt="">
    <img src="https://media.istockphoto.com/photos/homemade-vanilla-ice-cream-scoops-in-glass-bowl-picture-id954491574" class="ice2" alt="">
    <img src="https://media.istockphoto.com/photos/ice-cream-in-couple-hands-picture-id1173648810" class="ice3" alt="">
    <img src="https://media.istockphoto.com/photos/strawberry-vanilla-chocolate-ice-cream-with-waffle-cone-on-marble-picture-id1161805849" class="ice4" alt="">
  </div>

  <div class="dots">
    <label for="img1"></label>
    <label for="img2"></label>
    <label for="img3"></label>
    <label for="img4"></label>
  </div>
</div>
```